# Nginx: How to redirect each http:port requests to HTTPS:port in the below config?

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

Here is my nginx.conf, works fine for https.

If someone types **HTTP**://dev.local.org:3002, how do I redirect to **HTTPS**://dev.local.org:3002  ?

This nginx is inside a docker-compose container.

```
worker_processes 1;
events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

#set $my_server_name _ #TODO global variable does not work?

http {
    #DOCKER DNS - using this to resolve docker-compose hosts like 'appsearch', 'kibana' etc
    resolver 127.0.0.11 ipv6=off;

    #include mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;
    #TO read external configuration
    include sites-enabled/*.conf;


    server {  #DEFAULT SERVER
        listen  443 ssl; # Security change
        server_name _;

        include common.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/ssl.conf;

        location / {
            root    html;
            index   index.html  index.htm;
            include common_location.conf;
        }

        error_page  500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root html;
        }

#        location /appsearch { #TODO this /appsearch did not forward. find how to do it.
#              rewrite ^/appsearch(.*) /$1 break;
#              resolver 127.0.0.11 valid=30s ;
#              set $backend http://appsearch:3002;
#              proxy_pass $backend; # Use variable To avoid upstream host not found error.
#        }

    }#server80

    server {
      listen        9200 ssl;
      server_name   _;

      include common.conf;
      include /etc/nginx/ssl.conf;

      location / {
        set $backend http://elasticsearch:9200;
        proxy_pass $backend; # Use variable To avoid upstream host not found error.
        include common_location.conf;
      }
    }#server

    server {
      listen        3002 ssl;
      #server_name   dev.local.org; #TODO yuck, bad to add server name!
      server_name   _;
      include   common.conf;
      include /etc/nginx/ssl.conf;

      location / {
        set $backend http://appsearch:3002;
        proxy_pass $backend; # Use variable To avoid upstream host not found error.
        include common_location.conf;
      }
    }#server

    server {
      listen        5601;
      server_name   _;
      include   common.conf;
      include   /etc/nginx/ssl.conf;

      location / {
        set $backend http://kibana:5601;
        proxy_pass $backend; # Use variable To avoid upstream host not found error.
        include common_location.conf;
      }
    }#server
}
```

Comment: I don't think it is possible at all. You can listen either for HTTP requests or for HTTPS requests on one particular port, but not for the both types.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the 497 HTTP error to redirect: (source: https://meabed.com/http-497-status-code/)

In your conf you would add something like this:

````
 
  listen      1234 ssl;

  server_name your.site.tld;

  ssl         on;

  error_page  497 https://$host:1234$request_uri;
  
}```
````

Comment: Wow, it is really working! Thank you, didn't know about it. The only thing, this would produce a 302 redirection, and if you need a 301 one, you should use `error_page  497 =301 https://$host:1234$request_uri;` instead (already checked it).